# Spring MVC annotation and security configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

There are 2 Roles
1) ROLE_USER1
2)ROLE_USER2

I dont want to add every URI in spring-security.xml Example I have Manage User module, Where i can Create, Update, Delete and Read Users I have one controller named user controller. Mapping in that controller is

```
@RequestMapping (value="user/create")
@RequestMapping (value="user/list")
@RequestMapping (value="user/update")
@RequestMapping (value="user/delete")
```

I want ROLE_USER1 to only access "user/create" so in this case i have to add URI "user/create" for ROLE_USER1 role in secruity.xml

And  ROLE_USER2  can access only "user/list" and "user/delete", In this case i have to add 2 URI's for ROLE_USER2 in security.xml

I want if this could happen somehow that i will always give /admin in URL that Admin role can access

And for SuperAdmin URL will contain /SuperAdmin

And I just have to give /Admin/** and /superAdmin/** in spring-security.xml

But to achieve the above scenario I have to add Multiple mappings in controller for single action. If I add multiple actions then i Have Jsp Action problem. i.e there could be either "/admin/user/create" or "/superAdmin/user/create"

I want to secure url's with minimum entries in Spring.security.xml

Regards

Comment: Why would you need 2 urls for that?! The url `admin/user/create/` or maybe even better `/user/create` should be protected by Spring Security and only allow access for either role. You don't want to add a whole bunch of URIs just for security.

Comment: Yes.. Example i have created a UserCOntroller where all the action related to user are written .
So if i want to admin to access view users only then i have to add all the URI in security file. I dont want to add each URI in security file

Comment: I don't understand what you want, you don't want multiple urls as that becomes a maintaince hell so to speak. Just protect the `/admin/user/create` in Spring Security. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#authorize-requests

Comment: Or use annotations on the method `@PreAuthorize` to apply security.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum
Thank you for giving your precious time.

I have edited the original problem, Please have a look. Hope this time i will be able to explain properly

Comment: You don't want to change your URI's just because of roles. What happens if you add a 'SuperDuperAdminWhichCanAccessTheWorld` role you would have to change all the jsps, controllers, etc. Whereas adding it to Spring Security would be a single line. But as I already mentioned in another comment you could also annotate the handler methods with `@PreAuthorize` that way the confguration is part of your controller instead of Spring Security configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should create a new Controller for admin and superadmin.

Instead you should just add the roles to the URL in security.xml. For example, if your current security.xml configuration is as below

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/create" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER1')" />     
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/delete" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER2')" />
```

You just need to add admin and superadmin roles as below.

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/create" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER1', 'SuperAdmin', 'Admin')" />      
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/delete" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER2', 'SuperAdmin', 'Admin')" />
```

In you Java code, if you have any special logic for different roles, you can access the current role as below and switch the logic.

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
```